# Joomla Configuration - URL change

Tags: joomla

So I've changed the URL on a clients joomla site and it doesnt seem to be rendering properly anymore. The site was on a public domain, but I moved the dns to another host. I can still access the site through a host generated URL but like I said, its not rendering as expected.

Any pointers much appreciated!

Comment: I assume you have waited 24-48 hours for the name servers to be updated for the domain yes?

Answer (score 1):

- Try clearing your cache and Joomla's own cache
- Make sure that the $live_site variable is set to the new site if it was set to the old domain
- Make sure that the paths to the tmp and the logs directories are correct in the configuration.php file
- Make sure that your CSS files do not absolutely reference images/other CSS files on the old domain
- Make sure that your .htaccess file doesn't include any absolute references to the old domain